# Wine on macOS, does it support 16 bit color in window mode?

Tags: wine

I am trying to use Wine to run an old Windows game on macOS: so far the fullscreen mode does work fine, but the game checks for 16 bit color depth support and prevents Wine from running it in window mode.

I am wondering if there is something I could do on Wine's end (using the Mac driver, not X11 server).

ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth#High_color_(15/16-bit)